# Cleaning up after MonetDB heap memory allocation error

Tags: monetdb

I executed improper sql statement that syntactically correct but caused MonetDB to fail at allocating heap memory trying to allocate 490G. In result disk ran out of space and seems MonetDB never cleaned up. One of the subdirs in /bat holds 127G which I think was the one generated during that query execution. 
How can I reclaim that space? 
Also, in which directories does the actual data reside that represents columns?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue so decided to self answer in case someone else will run into the same problem. Because partition with dbfarm was completely filled mclient would not start. After I freed some space and run mclient again, then MonetDB was able to clean up and recover disk space.

Comment: Full disks are one of the most common issues people run into when using MonetDB...