# MonetDB Full Disk How To Manually Free Space

Tags: monetdb

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112839/cleaning-up-after-monetdb-heap-memory-allocation-error/29113188#29113188), essentially I forgot a clause in a join when using MonetDB that produced an enormous result that filled the disk on my computer. Monetdb didn't clean up after this and despite freeing space and waiting 24 hours the disk is still much fuller than it should be.

See below the size of the database in monetdb (In GB):

```
sql>SELECT CAST(SUM(columnsize) / POWER(1024, 3) AS INT) columnSize FROM STORAGE();
+------------+
| columnsize |
+============+
|        851 |
+------------+
1 tuple
```

And the size of the farm on disk:

```
sudo du -hs ./*
3,2T    ./data_warehouse
5,5M    ./merovingian.log
```

The difference in size is unexplained and appeared suddenly after launching the query that generated an extremely large result.

I can track these files down into the `merovingian.log` file and the `BAT` directory inside `warehouse` where many large files named after integers and `.tail` or `.theap` can be found.:

```
sudo du -hs ./*
2,0T    ./data_warehouse
1,3T    ./merovingian.log
4,0K    ./merovingian.pid
```

My question is how can I manually free this disk space without corrupting the database? Can any of these files be safely deleted or is there a command that can be launched to get MonetDB to free this space?

So far I've tried the following with no effect:

- Restarting the database
- Installing the latest version of the database (last time this happened), my current version is: `MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v11.37.11 (Jun2020-SP1)`
- Various `VACUUM` and `FLUSH` commands documented [here](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/SQLReference/LoggingProcedures), (Note that `VACUUM` doesn't run on my version)
- Checking online and reading the mailing list

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, during the query execution, MonetDB will free up memory/files that are no longer needed. But if that doesn't happen, you can try the following manual clean up.

First, lock and stop the database (it's called `warehouse`?):

```
monetdb lock warehouse
monetdb stop warehouse
```

You can fairly safely remove the `merovingian.log` to gain 1.3T (this log file can contain useful information for debugging, but in its current size, it's a bit difficult to use). The `kill` command is to tell `monetdbd` to start a new log file:

```
rm /<path-to>/merovingian.log
kill -HUP `pgrep monetdbd`
```

Then restart the database:

```
monetdb release warehouse
monetdb start warehouse
```

During the start-up, the MonetDB server should clean up the left-over transient data files from the previous session.

---

Concerning the size difference between `SUM(columnsize)` and on-disk size:

- there can be index files and string heap files. Their sizes are reported in separate columns returned by `storage()`.
- In your case, the database directory probably contains a lot of intermediate data files generated for the computation of your query.

Comment: Thanks Jennie, in the end the final commands that worked for me were `monetdbd stop` and `monetdbd start`

Comment: Glad to know your problem has been resolved. Did you really restart the MonetDB daemon?  That's a surprise. Restarting the particular database will cause the database server to clean up, then it shouldn't matter if you restart the daemon or not...  But thanks for sharing the working information.